# Java HttpURLConnection http timeout

Tags: java

In my local it works perfectly, but when I deploy it gives me this error

```
 nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

with https everything works normal, but http does not work and it gives me the timeout error.
I also just did the tests with restTemplate, OkHttpClient and I get the same result

What am I doing wrong or what should I configure to work, I hope your help, I would be too grateful

```
public String getFile(String baseName, String extensioFile) {
    String rpt;
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    String urlDonwload = "http://datos.susalud.gob.pe/node/223/download";
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlDonwload);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(900000);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(7200000);
        
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10, disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                // fileName = urlCamaUci.substring(urlCamaUci.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                // urlCamaUci.length());
                LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String formatDateTime = currentDate.format(formatter);
                System.out.println();
                fileName = baseName + "_" + formatDateTime.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "-") + "." + extensioFile;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            // String saveFilePath = PATH + File.separator + fileName;

            File pathSave = new File(fileName);

            

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pathSave.getCanonicalPath());
            
            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            rpt = pathSave.getCanonicalPath();

        } else {
            rpt = "FAILED";
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error search path");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        rpt = "FAILED";
    }

    return rpt;

}
```

Comment: It could be a firewall or some kind of network configuration that causes it. If you can, try running `curl http://datos.susalud.gob.pe/node/223/download` on the server you deploy to. If that also gives you a connection/timeout error, then the problem is not your code.

Comment: maybe the hosted server do not serve / open port for http? Have you tried to access it via postman or any other client tool?

Comment: Or perhaps something else? Neither work from AU.

Comment: I just ran on the server and I get this. curl: (7) Failed to connect to datos.susalud.gob.pe port 80: Connection timed out